# best practices to deal with polymorphism in .net core

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, polymorphism, model-binding

Suppose i have 3 classes A, B and C:

```
public class A{

}

public class B : A{

}

public class C : A{

}
```

in my Api i have:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Post([FromBody] A a)
 {   
   var new_a = addToDb(a); // add a to the db...
   return Created("", new_a);
 }
```

in this example **addToDb(A a)** represent adding a value to a database using the repository pattern with polymorphic behavior.

the problem is that the JSON converter doesn't cast A as B or C depending on the input. what is the best alternative to this problem? i already tried adding multiple dedicated functions for each derived class like this:

```
 [HttpPost("/B")]
 public ActionResult Post([FromBody] B a)
 {
   var new_a = addToDb(a); // add a to the db...
   return Created("", new_a  as B);  
 }
```

but adding all these functions didn't felt right.
is there any better alternative? please help

Comment: What does `JSON converter doesn't cast A as B or C depending on the input` mean? If you use A to receive, then you will never know whether you need to convert A to B or C, because A contains the common attributes of B and C.
If you need to add data to B or C separately to the database, you really should create the corresponding methods separately.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post([FromBody] A a)
    {
        var new_a = addToDb(a); // add a to the db...
        if (a.GetType() == typeof(B))
            return Created("", (B)new_a);           
        else
            return Created("", (C)new_a);            
    }
```